# PHP/JavaScript not reading text file

Tags: javascript, php, html, gps

I have a problem with a PHP/JavaScript I have downloaded in an example for a hardware project off the internet.

Below is the script, and I have a file server side with GPS co-ordinates called "gps.txt".  By placing the 'old' "i'm here" text commands I was able to figure out that the script does not appear to be opening the "gps.txt" files hence that is why Google maps is not being updated with markers.

Really appreciate any suggestions you guys have.

```
<!-- Load Jquery -->

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load Google Maps Api -->

<!-- IMPORTANT: change the API v3 key -->

<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCU0-w2UAK0Y1rFwVsaQxkMS0upbw-Cqyk&sensor=false"></script>

<!-- Initialize Map and markers -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(26.707687,-80.054420);
    var marker;
    var map;
    var mapProp;

    function initialize()
    {
        mapProp = {
          center:myCenter,
          zoom:15,
          mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
        setInterval('mark()',5000);
    }

    function mark()
    {
        map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
        var file = "gps.txt";
        $.get(file, function(txt) { 
            var lines = txt.split("\n");
            for (var i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
                console.log(lines[i]);
                var words=lines[i].split(",");
                if ((words[0]!="")&&(words[1]!=""))
                {
                    marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                          position:new google.maps.LatLng(words[0],words[1]),
                          });
                    marker.setMap(map);
                    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(words[0],words[1]));s
                }
            }
            marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        });

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

```
<!-- Draw information table and Google Maps div -->

    <div>
        <center><br />
            <b> SIM908 GPS position DEMO </b><br /><br />
            <div id="superior" style="width:800px;border:1px solid">
                <table style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Time</td>
                        <td>Satellites</td>
                        <td>Speed OTG</td>
                        <td>Course</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="time">2015 Apr 24 - 15:04</td>
                        <td id="sat"></td>
                        <td id="speed"></td>
                        <td id="course"></td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
            <br /><br />
            <div id="googleMap" style="width:800px;height:700px;"></div>
        </center>
    </div></body>
```

Comment: what's the specific error message?

Comment: Your file must be visible at the URL you're trying to load it from, it looks like `/gps.txt`.

Comment: @dandavis doesn't look like there is an error message.  This is the script running right now, and short of not loading the GPS co-ordinates everything appears to be good. Check http://67.205.215.217/demo_sim908.php

Comment: @KorvinSzanto I just tried switching the | var file = "/gps.txt" | in the code but it still doesn't look like it's reading the file.

Comment: @AlekseyMatyushev, you don't need to change that value, you need to figure out WHERE the file lives. JavaScript doesn't have access to your filesystem, it just requests the file from your webserver.

Comment: @KorvinSzanto so right now it lives in the same folder as the php script. So if I go to http://67.205.215.217/gps.txt you can see it.

Comment: @AlekseyMatyushev then the change to `var file = "/gps.txt"` is a good one, you're likely successfully loading the file but failing to parse it somehow. Check out [this guide to using the chrome developer console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console). With that, you should be able to view the actual request as it happens and identify any issues.

Comment: @AlekseyMatyushev looking at the script you linked to, you aren't defining `$`. You're failing to include jQuery.

Comment: @KorvinSzanto I'll read through the chrome developer console, looks like a valuable too.  Can you tell me how to define $ and include jQuery?

Comment: Figured it out using @KorvinSzanto suggestions.  Replaced the 3rd line above with:  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

After discussing through comments we found out that the answer to this question was to fix the jQuery `<script ...></script>` tag.